# How to run Applet

Tags: java

please give me an Applet example and say how yo run an applet
because applets doesn't have main and my IDE doesn't run it!
please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having problems creating/embeding a JApplet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559570/having-problems-creating-embeding-a-japplet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with reading this tutorial http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/

Comment: I think the OP is asking for an introduction to *developing* an applet, not for deploying it.

Answer (score 1):

See [Creating, Compiling, and Running an Applet](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/JavaInDOS.html#APPLETS).  Just involves create an HTML file and your .class files like this:

```
<html>
 <p> This file launches the 'A' applet: A.class! </p>  
 <applet code="A.class" height=200 width=320>
 No Java?!
 </applet>
</html>
```